Geometry Nodes - Edge Fade, Distance Decay?
I'm trying to replicate an effect that I created in Grasshopper. its an edge fade, where my pattern (in this case a sine wave) fades according to some profile when it is within a set distance from the edge of the mesh.
I've created a sin wave with distance decay/fade, but I don't know how to reference the edge of the mesh in geometry nodes.
The solution should work for irregular surfaces, or surfaces with holes in them too...
I'm using Blender 4.2 in case that matters.
Any suggestions?


Do you try a Vertex Group to tag the edge controlling the decay ? Is it always a strait line ?

I eventually figured it out. I was trying to seperate values that were higher or lower than some edge distance value, but it turns out the 'from max' value of the map range node effectively does that for you.

